# "С уважением, имярек"

Tags: пунктуация

Когда подписываешь письмо "С уважением(,) такой-то", нужна ли запятая после "с уважением"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чисто интуитивно предполагаю, что запятая нужна. Можно считать, что это два предложения. В одном говорится об отношении к адресату, второе - просто подпись. Можно "расшифровать" это так: "Я пишу к Вам с уважением. Я имярек."
 Но я не специалист.

Answer (score 1):

Правила русского языка не регламентируют этот случай, однако в деловой переписке сложилась практика, что запятая ставится.

Ссылки по теме:

- [заметка на грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/55-punct)
- [С уважением, (мн. ч.)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/434457/182097)