# «С уважением, (мн. ч.)»

Tags: грамотная-речь, этикет

Можно ли так завершать письма, когда в подписи указана группа людей?

> С уважением,
>   команда модераторов

Comment: Это — единственное.

Comment: @shampar да, *команда* — ед. ч. В данном случае не воспринимайте мн. ч. как грамматический термин, обратите внимание на смысловой аспект.

Comment: Уже не воспринимаю.

Comment: @shampar благодарю :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда речь идёт о коллективной подписи, слова "с уважением" отнюдь не обязательны, но вполне возможны. Они располагают читателя к команде, представляющей собой, как это ему обязательно покажется,  коллектив одинаково чувствующих и согласно мыслящих людей.

Мне интересно ещё, почему ставят запятую после "с уважением".

Comment: По мнению Грамоты.ру запятая здесь обусловлена сложившейся практикой письма.